# Count word with underscore

Tags: perl

How to change name "Happyending-qwertt_asdf_mnb_ko_sdf" into count 4.
Name Happyending will remain always constant,in short I have to count number of "underscores" and change it into count.

Thanks,

Comment: $_ = 'Happyending-qwertt_asdf_mnb_ko_sdf'; print tr/_//;

Answer (score 3):

You could use [transliteration](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr%2fSEARCHLIST%2fREPLACEMENTLIST%2fcdsr)

> If the REPLACEMENTLIST is empty, the SEARCHLIST is replicated. This latter is useful for counting characters in a class or for squashing character sequences in a class.

```
my $count = $string =~ tr/_//;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change the string, you could use this

```
my $string = "Happyending-qwertt_asdf_mnb_ko_sdf";

my $count = () = $string =~ m/_/g;
```

Comment: `tr///` is always going to be more efficient than `m///`.

Comment: @DaveCross Yes, but in this case, I do not believe there is any noticeable difference :-)

Comment: Well, you don't know how many times the code will be executed, so I'm not sure that you really have much to base your belief on :-)

Comment: @DaveCross None of us know it, only the asker knows.